# Can you predict where in memory a vector might move when growing?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector

I'm learning about C++ and have a conceptual question. Let's say I have a vector. I know that my vector is stored in contiguous memory, but let's say my vector keeps growing and runs out of room to keep the memory contiguous. How can I predict where in memory the vector will go? I'm excluding the option of using functions that tell the vector where it should be in memory.

Comment: What's the use-case for needing to know?

Comment: What good would it do you if you could? You can't ise the new address until after the growth, and you can't use the old address afterwards, and in both cases you shouldn't be using the actual address at all.

Comment: @Barry - I think he's trying to learn behavior and discover some inner workings. That's if I am parsing this correctly: *"I'm learning about C++ and have a conceptual question"*.

Comment: @jww you are correct. I don't have a particular use-case. I've been watching video's about vectors in C++, thought of this question, but couldn't find the answer (until now).

Answer (score 3):

If it "runs out of room to keep the memory contiguous", then it simply *won't* grow. Attempting to add items past the currently allocated size will (typically) result in its throwing an exception (though technically, it's up to the allocator object to decide what to do--it's responsible for memory allocation, and responding when that's not possible.

Note, however, that this could result from running out of address space (especially on a 32-bit machine) rather than running out of actual memory. A typical virtual memory manager can reallocate physical pages (e.g., 4 KB or 8 KB chunks) and write data to the paging file if necessary to free physical memory if needed--but when/if there's not enough contiguous address space, there's not much that can be done.

Comment: `std::vector<>`(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is a dynamic container capable of growing to the needed size, provided sufficient memory can be allocated from whatever allocator is supplied to its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends highly on your allocation strategy, but in general, the answer is no. Most allocators do not provide you with information where the next allocation will occur. If you were writing a custom allocator, then you could potentially make this information accessible, but doing so is not necessarily a good idea unless your use case specifically requires this knowledge.

The `realloc` function is the only C function which will attempt to grow your memory in place, and it makes no guarantees that it will do so.

Neither `new` nor `malloc` provide any information for where the "next" allocation will take place. You could potentially guess, if you knew the exact implementation details for your specific compiler, but this would be very unwise to rely on in a real program. Regarding specifically the `std::allocator` used for `std::vector`, it also does not provide details about where future allocations will take place.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could predict it in a particular situation, it would be extremely fragile - all it takes is one function you call to change to make another call to `new` or `malloc` [unless you are using a very specific allocation method - which is different from the "usual" method] to "break" where the next allocation is made.

If you KNOW that you need a certain size, you can use `std::vector::resize()` to set the size of the vector [or `std::vector<int> vec(10000);` to create a pre-sized to 10000, for example] - which of course is not guaranteed to work, but it guarantees that you never need "enough space to hold 3x the current content", which is what happens with `std::vector` when you grow it using `push_back` [and if you are REALLY unlucky, that means that your vector will use `2*n-1` elements, leaving `n-1` unused, because your size is `n-1` and you add ONE more element, which doubles the size, so now `2*n`, and you only actually require one more element...

Answer (score 1):

The internal workings of STL containers are kept private for good reasons. You should never be accessing any container elements through any mechanism other than the appropriate iterators; and it is not possible to acquire one of those on an element that does not yet exist.

You could however, supply an allocator and use that to deterministically place future allocations.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you predict where in memory a vector might move when growing?

As others like EJP, Jerry and Mats have said, you cannot determine the location of a "grown" vector until after it grows. There are some corner cases, like the allocator providing a block of memory that's larger than required so that the vector does not actually move after a grow. But its not something you should depend on.

In general, stacks grow down and heaps grow up. This is an artifact from the old memory days. Your code segment was sandwiched between them, and it ensured your program would overwrite its own code segment and eventually cause an illegal instruction. So you *might* be able to guess the new vector is going to be higher in memory than the old vector because the vector is probably using heap memory. But its not really useful information.

*If* you are devising a strategy for locating elements after a grow, then use an index and not an iterator. Iterators are invalidated after inserts and deletes (including the grow).

For example, suppose you are parsing the vector and you are looking for the data that follows `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. Once you know the offset of the data (byte 27 in the vector), then you can always relocate it in constant time with `v.begin() + 26`. If you only have part of the certificate and later add the tail of the data and the `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` (and the vector grows), then the data is still located at `v.begin() + 26`.

Answer (score 0):

No, in practical terms you can't predict where it will go if it has to move due to resizing.  However, it isn't so random that you could use it as a random number generator (;